# How to pull only one branch from remote?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-remote

I want to copy all of the code and folder structure to the master branch but still keep my changes in the develop branch. That's because I'd like to compare the branches and then merge them.

Sadly, when I use the clone command in Git bash the new code is also displayed when I switch to the develop branch, isn't the pupose of branches that you should be able to change one of them and the others are kept unaffected?

What am I doing wrong? (I'm using Eclipse if it's helpful) :)

Comment: The clone command copies the whole repository (i.e. all branches) to your local machine. When you say you want to "clone some code to the master branch," what do you mean? Do you want to copy over certain commits, certain files, or something else?

Comment: Okay, thanks! I want to copy all of the code and folder structure to the master branch but still keep my changes in the develop branch. That's because I'd like to compare the branches and then merge them. But I may have solved it if I checkout master and then write "git fetch" and "git reset --hard origin/master" instead

Comment: If you made any commits onto master since you last pushed, the steps you outlined would basically discard those commits. If you didn't make any commits since the last push, what you did is equivalent to the (much safer) `git pull`. Be very careful with `git reset` unless you know exactly what you are doing.